# How can I Curve my premade logo vector, around a circle in illustrator cs5?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Hi i want to curve my logo-text vector around A circle, like this:

[image]

With this (my logo):
[image]

But my logo is a premade vector, not text file, so each letter is its own SHAPE/Path or whatever you call it. So i want to arrange it around a circle perfectly like the powerhouse logo

how could i do this? thanks in advance

Comment: Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Warp > Arc

Comment: Thanks. Illustrator is giving the error "the selection contains objects which cant be distorted"

Comment: Oh it worked! i had to select with white arrow tool! thanks!

Comment: Well, well, well.... Here is exactly what you are looking for. To create something similar to this badge, simply check the source of the file you take inspiration from. This site - SpoonGraphics (and designer - Chris Spooner) is of great inspiration. Check [here](http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-create-a-retro-badgeemblem-style-logo)